# Unable to use getByRole on listitem with a specific name - RTL

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

My apologies If this is a duplicate question. I couldn't find an answer anywhere else.

Component:

```
<ul>
  <li>Pending tasks</li>
</ul>
```

Test code:

```
expect(getByRole("listitem", { name: "Pending tasks" })).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Error:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "listitem" and name "Pending tasks"
```

Here's the codesandbox link to reproduce this:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-browser-mrf78?file=/src/App.test.js

Even though it shows error saying unable to find, it still suggests me li & ul tags as the available roles.

```
Here are the accessible roles:
 --------------------------------------------------
  list:

  Name "":
  <ul />

  --------------------------------------------------
  listitem:

  Name "":
  <li />
```

Could someone please explain what am I missing here?
I tried using regex matchers but no luck.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A `listitem` is named by the Author by spec (https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#listitem).

Name from author is defined as

> author: name comes from values provided by the author in explicit markup features such as the aria-label attribute, the aria-labelledby attribute, or the host language labeling mechanism, such as the alt or title attributes in HTML, with HTML title attribute having the lowest precedence for specifying a text alternative.

-- https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#namecalculation

That does not mean you should give it an aria-label. You should only add aria attributes if you have identified an issue with assistive technology.

For your specific query I'd suggest `getAllByRole('listitem').find(listitem => listitem.textContent === 'Pending task')`.

Comment: As he is looking for a single element, I would suggest replace filter by find

Comment: If you know what position it's in: `within(screen.getAllByRole('listitem')[0]).getByText('Pending task')` 

Super educational answer, thank you!

Comment: This causes challenges with TS as the `find` can return `undefined`.